# How to get all the tracks of an artist with spotify api?

Tags: php, api, spotify

I am able to view all the tracks on spotify by calling this url:

> http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=xxx&page=1

*A sample response contains the artist data for each track, like:*

```
[artists] => Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
  (
    [href] => spotify:artist:38IfmizrHTCxFjd8UKhWnp
    [name] => Husman
  )
)
```

From the above response, i get the artist ID as: **38IfmizrHTCxFjd8UKhWnp**.

Now, is there a way to get all the tracks of the above artist (**38IfmizrHTCxFjd8UKhWnp**), with an api call ?

What i am trying to do is, i would like to display the tracks for each artist in my application.

I see that we can fetch the albums of an artist, with a call like:

http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:artist:4YrKBkKSVeqDamzBPWVnSJ&extras=albumdetail

But i found that there is no direct way of fetching the tracks of an artist, with the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, all you can do is a name-based track search, e.g. [http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=artist:Madonna](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=artist%3aMadonna) or any other search from the Advanced Search Syntax.

*The link to the [Advanced Search Syntax](http://www.spotify.com/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/) seems to be broken at the moment, but you should be able to look at [this cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3avv2_Lfg0f6IJ%3awww.spotify.com/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=se).*

If you're looking to make more powerful queries, I'd really suggest you have a look at [The Echonest's API](http://developer.echonest.com). It's quite awesome, and has supports for working with Spotify URI:s. Also, it's being continuously developed, whereas the web API Spotify's provided hasn't really evolved in the past years (but maybe it will, who knows).

Comment: with echonest, number of different songs you can get for an artist is also limited (by 100)

Answer (score 1):

Since the official advanced syntax is broken right now, you can find it in the web-archive:
http://web.archive.org/web/20120704131650/http://www.spotify.com/us/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

In the Spotify Developer Home i found this ( https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/ )

http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist?q=38IfmizrHTCxFjd8UKhWnp

Maybe help.

Comment: This link does not seem to give any valid response. It says: totalResults is 0.

Comment: Indeed. If I were you revise the manual Spotify API with the information that I have indicated.

Comment: Currently, it seems that, first we have to get the albums of the artist with API, and then send another request to API for getting the tracks of each of the albums of the artist.